# Form submission in ie

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I used `e.preventDefault();` to stop form submission, but it is not working in IE 8 using jQuery 1.8.2

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
             ..........
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: which version of IE ?

Comment: Please specify: What version of IE? What version of jQuery? What are the symptoms of "not working"? Do you get an error in the browser console? What have you done already to try to fix it?

Comment: @Spudley The form is submitting, not prevented in IE only.

Comment: try 1.8.3 since 1.8.2 is not publicly available unless you copy it. Both normalize but perhaps there is a bug in 1.8.2

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this code

```
if(e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault(); else e.returnValue = false;
```

Because e.preventDefault() is not supported in some versions of IE. In IE it is e.returnValue = false

Comment: jQuery normalizes the `preventDefault()` method, it works on IE.

Comment: @undefined When the first time I faced this problem, the above code helps me. After that I never forgot to add this part in my codes. ;)

Comment: Workind with jQuery as he seems he is doing, this is not needed.

Comment: Seems very strange since 1.8.2 and 1.8.3 have normalised the code: jQuery.Event.prototype = {
 preventDefault: function() {
  this.isDefaultPrevented = returnTrue;

  var e = this.originalEvent;
  if ( !e ) {
   return;
  }

  // if preventDefault exists run it on the original event
  if ( e.preventDefault ) {
   e.preventDefault();

  // otherwise set the returnValue property of the original event to false (IE)
  } else {
   e.returnValue = false;
  }
 },

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do this in jQuery is just `return false;` at the end of the callback.

Like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
        $.ajax({
             ..........
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

### What does return false?

Returning false performs three tasks when called:

- event.preventDefault();
- event.stopPropagation();
- Stops callback execution and returns immediately when called.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
e.returnValue = false;
```

instead of

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks. This is similar to the answer I choose. But that one is little bit better.

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
// Disabling submit action for the #myForm form
$('#myForm').bind("submit", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Living demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yA2Dr/

Comment: Works for me in IE8 on XP